# AMPL : defining two condition in one constraint

Tags: constraints, ampl

when I define my constraint in this way

```
subject to p_inj {p in Step,  k in Dest : type[k] == 2 || type[k] == 3}
```

it works but when I use :

```
subject to p_inj {p in Step : time[p] == 1 ,k in Dest : type[k] == 2 || type[k] == 3}
```

it does not work any more.

Can anyone explain why it does not work and if there is any way to make that work in this way or not?

also suppose my Step is like this :

```
Set Step : = 1 2 ;
```

is there any way that I can tell AMPL in this way :

```
subject to p_inj {p in Step : Step[p] == 1 ,k in BUS : bus_type[k] == 2 || bus_type[k] == 3}
```

I mean is there any way to use value of different elements of a set directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AMPL, as in algebraic notation, the "such that" clause should be at the end of the indexing expression:

```
subject to p_inj {p in Step, k in Dest:
                    time[p] == 1 && (type[k] == 2 || type[k] == 3)} ...
```

Regarding the second question, if I understood it correctly, you can do something like

```
subject to p_inj {p in {1}, k in BUS: bus_type[k] == 2 || bus_type[k] == 3} ...
```

or replace all occurrences of `p` in the constraint body with `1`.

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem =).

Comment: is there any way to work for the second part of my question? I mean now I define a param time just same as my set Step to be able to read it as time[p]... is there any way that it can read the Set directly

Comment: I've updated the answer trying to address the second part of your question too.